# Will Kinesis Client Library DynamoDB Adaptor Lose Data

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis, amazon-dynamodb-streams, amazon-kcl

The [DynamoDB Streams Kinesis Adaptor published on github here](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-streams-kinesis-adapter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/streamsadapter/model/ShardAdapter.java#L74)  has this function with the following comments:

> The Kinesis model provides an adjacent parent shard ID in the event of
>         a parent shard merge. Since DynamoDB Streams does not support merge, this
>         always returns null.

I am concerned about this and I will describe my concern using an example of 7 shards, for simplicity lets name them *0* to *6*.

*0*'s parent is no longer available due to retention policy, *1,2,3,4,5* are siblings due to high traffic on the DynamoDB table, all of them have *0* as their parent, and *6* is a currently open shard and was the result of a merge since traffic spike on the DynamoDB table came down. I will also assume it can have **only one parent** so randomly its parent is *3*.

So, does this mean if we start a Worker using this adapter against a DynamoDB Stream that has the above state, **it will only begin to process shard *0*, *3* and *6*??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learnt that DynamoDB Stream shards **never merge**. Even after traffic to the table had died down, each (parallel) shard will simply have lower throughput. The situation I described in my question will not happen.

Also seems like

> A DynamoDB Stream shard may have at most 1 parent and at most 2 children.

The bottom line I learn from this question is:

> Kinesis Client Library + the DynamoDB Streams Kinesis Adapter guarantees that all shards will be processed in order, except if you fall behind in processing a shard such that it is trimmed before you process it.